# get sibling node without relying on parent index?

Tags: dom, watir-webdriver

I find it easy to get the text values inside cells whose row has a reliable attribute, eg. `$browser.tr(:class, "datarow2_sm")`

However I also need to grab the data from the very next `<tr>` in the table, defined only as `<tr class="">`.
Its HTML contents don't have anything very unique either, watir-speaking.

One reluctant method to catch that row is:

```
 cell1value = $browser.tr(:class, "datarow2_sm").parent[3][1].text
 cell2value = $browser.tr(:class, "datarow2_sm").parent[3][2].text.to_f  # etc.
```

But I don't want to rely on a fixed index *[3]* as such things in the wider table may shift. In addition to **.parent** is there anything like *.sibling* (**.next**/**.previous** like in Mechanize)?  Perhaps one that would prefer a node of the same type (tr to another tr not a td or some non-row node in the DOM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the css adjacent sibling selector. Note that Watir-Webdriver only currently supports css selectors for elements node.

You would do the following (noting that the to_subtype is to convert it back to a TableRow rather than Element):

```
puts b.element(:css, "tr.datarow2_sm + tr").to_subtype.text
```

**Update**

If you want to get the second cell in that next row, you can do one of the following:

```
puts b.element(:css, "tr.datarow2_sm + tr").to_subtype[1].text  
puts b.element(:css, "tr.datarow2_sm + tr").td(:index, 1).text
```

Comment: So to grab only the 2nd cell's value of that adjacent row, is it like this?: `cell2value = $browser.element(:css, "tr.datarow2_sm + tr").to_subtype[2].text`

Comment: Watir-webdriver is zero-based index, so if you want the second cell it would actually be index 1. If you only care about the cell, you can actually skip the to_subtype. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has a special selector for this called [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
>   E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
>   share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
>   E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Comment: That is a better description of what I had in mind by "same types"